# Convert emoji to hex number

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to convert an emoji to an hex number or a string.

there is any way to convert this  in this : 0x00000000D83DDC71L or D83DDC71

**Edit**

my code is this:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emoji.ToString()); //emoji is 
var number = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0); //number is 2610470896
var emojiCode = unicode.ToString("X"); // emojiCode is 9B989FF0
```

the problem is that i need my emojiCode to be D83DDC71

i hope is more clear now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to hex-string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Could you be more specific? There's obvious solutions like converting the  filename or hash, but I suppose you thought about that already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do something like:

```
var str = "\uD83D\uDC71";
string res = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str)).Replace("-", "");
```

Note that you want your Unicode string to be in "big endian" mode (so `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`)

Probably easier without going through the `Encoding` conversion:

```
string res = string.Concat(str.Select(x => ((ushort)x).ToString("X4")));
```

(`ushort` and `char` are nearly the same thing, but `ushort` is built to be formatted as a number, while `char` is built to be formatted as a character)

Comment: @frenk91 You'll have to benchmark it... I don't program for Windows phones nor I do have one of them.

Comment: I have benchmarket the 2 method and the fastest way is to use the Encoding

Answer (score 0):

Emoji Unicode is not a single hex number, and it only encoding by UTF32.
So you could split it, like this:

```
byte[] utfBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("");
print(utfBytes.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < utfBytes.Length; i += 4)
{
     if (i != 0) result += '-';
     result += System.BitConverter.ToInt32(utfBytes, i).ToString("x2").ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post code without explanation. Please share with us your thoughts why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.