# C# Convert string to hex

Tags: c#, string, hex

I've search around a lot & keep getting a mixture of errors, I'm using a web api to convert some text to numbers (xuid) I then want to convert those numbers to a hexadecimal & keep getting an error saying the value was too large||small for an int32 code--

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/json");
        client.Headers.Add("X-AUTH", "ce0c28c65911893794ec47af634939b9445d2007");
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var fd = client.DownloadString("https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/" + Gamertag.Text);
        int decVal = int.Parse(fd, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        Xuid.Text = decVal.ToString();
```

Comment: I suggest the use `long` instead of `int`

Comment: How does your hex number (which is likely too big) look like?

Comment: Show us what `fd` is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

An int variable holds a number, not a representation of the number. So use

```
 Xuid.Text = decVal.ToString("X");
```

For the required output