# Hex.decodeHex equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone please suggest the C# equivalent of `Hex.decodeHex()` which is in Java.

Below the example in java:

```
Key = "7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777";
byte[] KeyInBytes = Hex.decodeHex(Key.toCharArray());
```

I am looking for the c# equivalent of this

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: How about explain what that does, in words and stuff :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp

Please refer to this link. Might be exactly what you need

Comment: @TheGeneral decodeHex() Converts an array of characters representing hexadecimal values into an array of bytes of those same values.

Answer (score 6):

In .NET 5 and later you can use [`Convert.FromHexString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score -1):

[Convert string to hex-string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp), I think that you are trying to do something like this.
I think it is  `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Key);` as the previous link shows

Comment: This is not correct. `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Key)` does something completely different

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).