# string.Equals evaluates to false

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have two strings:

- `lp.Name`

  A string returned from a backend server database contained in the class `LocalPlayer`:

  ```cs
  public class LocalPlayer
  {
       public string Name;
  }
  ```
- `playerName`

  A local string variable.

Here is the code block I am running:

```
private void UpdatePlayer()
{
    bool localPlayerFound = false;

    if (player != null)
    {
        if (player.localPlayers != null)
        {
            if (player.localPlayers.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (LocalPlayer lp in player.localPlayers)
                {

                   Debug.Log("Name =" + lp.Name + " Length " + lp.Name.Length + " Bytes " + string.Join(",", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(lp.Name)));
                   Debug.Log("Name =" + playerName + " Length " + playerName.Length + " Bytes " + string.Join(",", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(playerName)));

                    bool areEqual = string.Equals(lp.Name.Trim(), playerName.Trim());

                    Debug.Log(areEqual);

                    if (areEqual)
                    {
                        localPlayerFound = true;
                        // Fill out Player stats
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (localPlayerFound == false) // NO players yet in Local Database - Create a new one
    {
        AddNewLocalPlayer();
    }
}
```

The output of the Debug statements are:

After a few suggestions I added Length and encoding to the debug statements. Here is what comes up in the debug statements.

```
Name =Flash Length 5 Bytes 70,0,108,0,97,0,115,0,104,0


Name =Flash​ Length 6 Bytes 70,0,108,0,97,0,115,0,104,0,11,32


False
```

If trim doesn't remove the hidden characters, what can I use?

It says that The output confirms that byte 11 corresponds to the vertical tab character, and byte 32 corresponds to the space character.

Thanks

Comment: print string's length in addition to name, probably some non printable symbols are here

Comment: All strings are UTF-16. Why do you expect the strings to be equal to begin with, because they look equal in the debug window? Do they have the same `Length` after the trim? What bytes are contained in their `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()`?

Comment: Please share a [mre], like: https://onlinegdb.com/sqlB4w83w

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. When I compare Length, one is 5 and one is 6. If trim doesn't remove the hidden characters, what can I use? Thanks

Comment: Take the conclusion that those string are not equal (because length is different)? Or take a look at [Convert string to hex-string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999604/convert-string-to-hex-string-in-c-sharp), which should explain more about those strings.

Comment: "The output of the Debug statements are:...."   After your last edit, this is no longer TRUE, please update  

Comment: The difference can be seen by looking at the contents of this `System.Byte[]` that is in your debuglog.   Please replace `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(lp.Name)` by: `string.Join(",",System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(lp.Name))`, so we can see the contents of that array.

Comment: Please vote to have this question re-opened. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason this character [ᄲ](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1132) is at the end of your string. And trim will not remove it (which is OK!)   Or is it [㈑](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3211) ....   I always get the order of those thing wrong......

Comment: What character is represented by 11, 32? . How would I write a RegEx statement to remove this character?

Comment: Before writing a regex, you should now which characters are valid.  (Because there are more character invalid, when talking about Unicode, then valid, to store a name which is readable to the Western World.)

Comment: Or you could use Substring() (But how do you know that you want to remove only the last character?  (see: https://onlinegdb.com/YF4bH-zTJ )

Comment: _What character is represented by 11, 32? . How would I write a RegEx statement to remove this character?_ If it were me, I'd be thinking about what characters  I want to _allow_.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> If trim doesn't remove the hidden characters, what can I use?

Consider using [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-8.0#definition) which would offer a highly customizable fallback option. Here are three basic extensions to try for starters, any of which work on the specific case you show.

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic examples.
/// </summary>
static partial class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// First pass. Very basic.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToSafeCompare(this string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

    /// <summary>
    /// Use categories. Attempts to keep letters, marks, numbers, symbols, punctuation.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToVisibleCharacters(this string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input, "[^\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{N}\\p{P}\\p{S}]", "");

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove control characters
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToNegateControlCharacters(this string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input, "\\p{C}", "");

}
```

###### Console mock with the provided test bytes shown in the post.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Console.Title = "Try Regex";

string flash1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[]{ 70, 0, 108, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0 });
string flash2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(new byte[] { 70, 0, 108, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 11, 32 });

Console.WriteLine($"{flash1} {flash2}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(flash1, flash2));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Basic alphanumeric");
var test1A = flash1.ToSafeCompare();
var test1B = flash2.ToSafeCompare();
Console.WriteLine($"{test1A} {test1B}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(test1A, test1B));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Prelim filter using character categories");
var test2A = flash1.ToVisibleCharacters();
var test2B = flash2.ToVisibleCharacters();
Console.WriteLine($"{test2A} {test2B}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(test2A, test2B));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Prelim filter removes control characters");
var test3A = flash1.ToNegateControlCharacters();
var test3B = flash2.ToNegateControlCharacters();
Console.WriteLine($"{test3A} {test3B}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Equals(test3A, test3B));

Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: console log]

Comment: Brilliant! , Thanks so much! You just made my whole day!